# Microsoft SQL Server host config path \\?\C:

Tags: sitecore

I am in the process of setting up a Sitecore CMS on a Windows 2008 server and I have it mostly setup but the web address to my local on the computer is giving me a 500 error.

When I look at the configurations the site is using, it's trying to reach the `web.config` file through an odd path

```
\\\?\C:\inept\siteproject\web.config
```

I am curious about the `\\\?\` is that correct or did I miss a setting? I am not even sure if the configuration is able to access the `web.config` file either.

I went through the docs in Sitecore and followed a speedy video tut on installing it and so far this odd root file path is the only thing I can think of as being wrong.

Appreciate the help

Ben

Comment: That's really strange! I presume you used the .exe installer? I would try uninstalling (from Control Panel > Programs & Features) and re-installing...

Comment: sadly the recommended installer is not an option at this point, trying to resolve that. took a pre-built site using sitecore and attempting to drag and drop onto windows server and configure the server to use it.

Comment: The `\\?\` prefix can be used to manage Windows paths that are longer than the usual 260 character limit. So this should not be anything funky at all - unusual that it's being used on such a short path, but should work just fine, no matter what

Comment: `When I look at the configurations the site is using...` -  Where did you look this up? Where is that line in config that you mention exactly?

Comment: If you are setting the site up manually you may want to watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=It4JAcpv8qg

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the path but the error typically means you have a bad web.config. Try going into iis, select the site node and try opening any of the settings (default document etc.). This will typically give you a more descriptive error message with a line number regarding what's wrong with the config. Also make sure you have the correct path set as the physical location under basic settings in iis.